# How can I make snake like X axis in d3

Tags: d3.js

I need to make axis with curves at its edges in d3, and it can be scrolled down and show more data.
Is it possible with d3?

[image: example image]

Tried to use [d3-radial-axis](https://github.com/vasturiano/d3-radial-axis) library, but without success.
They only have example for radial scale and for spiral scale.